# "Failed to specialize function template" when trying to pass member function of another class

Tags: function, templates, c++11, lambda, function-pointers

I have been trying to assign class's member function to a std::function but it throws compile time error **Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)**

Below is the header file of that class :

```
class TypeAnalysis {
public: 
    bool AnalysisHelper(std::string filePath);
    void createTypeTable(std::string dir, std::string pattern, size_t nThread = 3);
    std::vector<std::string> getFiles(std::string dir, std::vector<std::string> patterns);
private:

};
```

And below is createtypeTable function where I am assigning AnalysisHelper method to std::fnuction object.

```
void TypeAnalysis::createTypeTable(std::string dir, std::string pattern, size_t nThread)
{
    Threadpool<bool, std::string> tp(10);
    DataContext dc;
    tp.start();
    std::vector<std::string> patterns = SH::split(pattern);
    std::vector<std::string> files = getFiles(dir, patterns);
    std::function<bool(std::string)> w = &TypeAnalysis::AnalysisHelper; //I think issue is here
    try {
        if (files.size() > 0) {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
                WorkItem<bool, std::string> *wi1 = new WorkItem<bool, std::string>(&w, &files[i]);
                tp.doWork(wi1);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what();
        return;
    }
    tp.doWork(nullptr);
    tp.wait();
    DataContext::getContextThreadPool().doWork(nullptr);
}
```

When I tried to do the same without any class definition (AnalysisHelper was Glabal function and main had same body as createTypeTable), it worked fine.

Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is in this line:

```
std::function<bool(std::string)> w = &TypeAnalysis::AnalysisHelper;
```

I can not see this as correct operation. You are referencing  a `member function` of a `class`. This `member function` may need to edit or read one of the `member variables` of that `class`. It is not a `free function`. It is part of the `class` which should be called for a specific `object`. So it is normal that C++ denied that.

**Edit:**

I found this https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#memfnptr-vs-fnptr

> **How do I pass a pointer-to-member-function to a signal handler, X event callback, system call that starts a thread/task, etc?**
>
> Don’t.
>
> Because a member function is meaningless without an object to invoke it on,
> you can’t do this directly (if The X Window System was rewritten in
> C++, it would probably pass references to objects around, not just
> pointers to functions; naturally the objects would embody the required
> function and probably a whole lot more)

Answer (score 0):

Issue was I was not binding the method to any object. Changing

```
std::function<bool(std::string)> w = &TypeAnalysis::AnalysisHelper;
```

to

```
std::function<bool(std::string)> w = [=](std::string file) { return this->AnalysisHelper(file); };
```

worked.